# How to find SQL Azure Scale events in logs?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

Is it possible to identify when a SQL Azure scale happened in Azure and from what to what.

I have looked in activity log, but it just says that someone performed an event and not what that event was.

The DB Audit logs seem to show "within Database" events like RPC calls and the relevant SQL etc.

I did find this:

```
Select * 
FROM   sys.dm_operation_status AS o 
WHERE  o.resource_type_desc = 'DATABASE' 
ORDER  BY o.last_modify_time DESC;
```

Which is populated when a scale is happening, but not when finished or it is very temporary.

Thoughts?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Using PowerShell commands with some timestamps may help you determine the duration of the scale process.

```
# Get the database object
$sqlDB = Get-AzureRmSqlDatabase `
-ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName `
-ServerName $serverName `
-DatabaseName $databaseName

Write-Output "DB name: $($sqlDB.DatabaseName)" | timestamp
Write-Output "Current DB status: $($sqlDB.Status), edition: $($sqlDB.Edition), tier: $($sqlDB.CurrentServiceObjectiveName)" | timestamp


        Write-Output "Changing tier!" | timestamp
        $sqlDB | Set-AzureRmSqlDatabase -Edition $defaultEdition -RequestedServiceObjectiveName $defaultTier | out-null
        Write-Output "Change initiated." | timestamp
        $sqlDB = Get-AzureRmSqlDatabase -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -ServerName $serverName -DatabaseName $databaseName
        Write-Output "Current DB status: $($sqlDB.Status), edition: $($sqlDB.Edition), tier: $($sqlDB.CurrentServiceObjectiveName)" | timestamp
```